# Triangle with a bisected side and a trisected side

Tags: geometry

> In the figure, $P$ is the midpoint of $BC$, and $AR=RQ=QC$. Prove that:
>
> 1. $BR=4SR$
> 2. $\triangle ABC =12\triangle ASR$

[image]

From the given figure,
1). $BP=PC$

2). $\triangle APB=\triangle APC$,   $AP$ being the median of $\triangle ABC$

Now, what should I do next?

Comment: At first please replace the sketch with another of better proportions.(Points R,Q do not seem to trisect side AC).Why should BR and PQ be parallel?

Comment: @Narasimham, is the figure clear now?

Comment: Yes indeed we can now believe in the truth of what we going to prove using this new diagram :)

Answer (score 2):

$BP=PC, RQ=QC$ so $BR = 2PQ$ and $BR$ is parallel to $PQ$. Similarly, $PQ = 2SR$ because $AR = RQ$ and $SR$ is parallel to $PQ$. Hence, $BR = 2PQ = 4SR$. 
$\dfrac{S_{ASR}}{S_{ABC}} = \dfrac{S_{ASR}}{2S_{APC}} = \dfrac{AS\cdot AR}{2AP\cdot AC} = \dfrac{1}{2\cdot 3\cdot 2} = \dfrac{1}{12}$

Comment: #dezdichado, could you please explain me the second part of your proof?

Comment: If $T$ is a triangle with sides $x,y$ and angle $\alpha$ between them, then the area of $T$ is given by $\dfrac{xy\sin\alpha}{2}$.

Comment: now it's clear to me?

Answer (score 0):

It becomes rather obvious if you do an affine transformation onto an isosceles right-angled triangle on a square grid

[image]

and if affine transformations are too difficult, then construct a parallelogram grid with one side parallel to the base $BC$ (divided into $12$ parts) and the other parallel to the median $AP$ (divided into $6$ parts)

[image]